# Image on canvas to JPEG file

Tags: android, jpeg, android-canvas

I'm drawing 2D images on the canvas.

I want to save image shown on canvas to JPEG file, how can I do it?

Comment: Since the link you referred to is long since dead could you perhaps add a bit more context into the question itself?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. create an empty bitmap
2. create a new Canvas object and pass this bitmap to it
3. call view.draw(Canvas) passing it the canvas object you just created. [Refer Documentation of method for details.](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas)
4. Use Bitmap.compress() to write the contents of the bitmap to an OutputStream, file maybe.

Pseudo code:

```
Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

Comment: Hello Samuh,

I tried the code, it generates a jpeg file but does not have the canvas drawn shape or what ever I have written on canvas.

Any comment.


Thanks,
Ketan

Answer (score 12):

1. **set Drawing Cache Enabled**
2. Draw whatever you want
3. **Get Bitmap object from view**
4. Compress and save the image file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class CanvasTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Draw2d d = new Draw2d(this);
        setContentView(d);
    }

    public class Draw2d extends View {

        public Draw2d(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);          
            c.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);

            try {
                getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/arun.jpg")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error--------->", e.toString());
            }
            super.onDraw(c);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Somehow it feels like a bad idea to compress and save within the onDraw method.

Comment: it gives me a black image

Answer (score 6):

Canvas to JPG:

```
Canvas canvas = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
Bitmap bmpBase = null;

bmpBase = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_width, image_height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bmpBase);
// draw what ever you want canvas.draw...

// Save Bitmap to File
try
{
    fos = new FileOutputStream(your_path);
    bmpBase.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    fos = null;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if (fos != null)
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
            fos = null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```