# Is it possible to show image while i am drawing on the canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to show the image like pen while drawing on the canvas. It looks like i am drawing threw pen.
And while i stop drawing, the image of pen should be hide.

Is it possible to do ?
If yes then what should i have to do to make it ?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to use animation

Comment: I'm guessing that you want a canvas which the user can draw on to (like a painting app)? If so, you can just draw an image of a pen (onto the canvas) so that its point is where the user is pressing. But I think that'll be the least of your worries.

Comment: @FunkTheMonk : I am using canvas to do paint. But i want is, While i am moving my hand on the canvas to draw, the image like pen is displayed on the point i am tauching the screen. And if i touch up then the image of pen is hide.

Comment: Is there any code to do like this ?

Comment: Yes its possible go through to given link
[Saving canvas images][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/android-canvas-to-jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes 
take a bitmap in the canvas and draw it by specifying the coordinates

eg.

```
          int Down_yvalue=0;
          int Current_yvalue=0;
          Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face);
      canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, Down_yvalue, Current_yvalue, new Paint());
```

and ontouch event get the coordinates and redraw it by calling this method invalidate 
eg .

```
               public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
               Down_yvalue=(int)event.getX();
               Current_yvalue=(int) event.getY();
               invalidate() ;
            }
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me try it. . .

Comment: No, its not working as i want. . .  I mean while i am drawing on the canvas and where ever i touch on the screen, there and till that the image should be displayed.