# How to Save the drawing canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-canvas

I am using this API demo of the Developer site, [THIS DEMO.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)

But i am wonder that how to save that image in to My Andrtoid Device.
Is please anyone give the Code to save that drawn image to the Android Device.

Thanks.

Comment: Visit Following [Link][1] for the Answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/android-canvas-to-jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this code

```
View content = your_view;
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path+"/image.png");
FileOutputStream ostream;
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", 5000).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", 5000).show();
}
```

Comment: How can I also save the Background of the `view`? Right now that's saving the drawing only but not the background.

Comment: The answer said View content = you_view;   Correct me If I'm wrong, am I supposed to put my layout id or view id? I did this  View content = findViewById(R.id.content); and I got " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 1):

```
drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = null;
drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
bm=drawView.getDrawingCache();
```

Then write the bitmap to file using bitmap factory.

Answer (score 0):

One option is create another Canvas (as shown below) and repeat all your drawing on this new canvas.
Once done, call drawBitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(// Set the params you like //);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// Do all your drawings here

canvas.drawBitmap(// The first picture //);
```

The best would be if there was a way to copy an existing canvas and then you wont need to re-draw everything but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the below approach & worked for me.
Get your CustomView by using its id from xml file but not by instantiating the Customview.

```js
View v = findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
//don't get customview by this way, View v = new CustomView(this);
int canvasWidth = v.getWidth();
int canvasHeight = v.getHeight();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
v.draw(canvas);
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

All code should be inside saveButton click listener.