# Why can't I draw with my own canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

When I create a new `Canvas` in `onDraw()` like this:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(myBitmap);
```

and then use this to draw something, it dosen't work.

But when I use the `canvas` parameter from `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`, it works. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". You are probably going to have to edit your question to clarify that if you're looking for a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this  -

```
Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

And, see the related question from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/android-canvas-to-jpg)

and, try out the [Sampleapp](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17409605/WriteOnScreen.zip.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting? if you want to just draw a bitmap use the following code:

```
    @Override
           protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
           {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bak, 0, 0, null);
           }
```

Where "bak" is a bitmap. There is no need of a creating another extra Canvas again inside onDraw as its a redundancy.

Comment: but I want to draw a white area 320*240 .....when i use the canvas above like  canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); The whole screen is white