# how to paint over the image and save it

Tags: android, bitmap, android-custom-view, paint

I've built a customview to paint over a bitmap the problem is when I try to save or share the image only the original bitmap is saved without the painted lines over it, here's the code i use for custom view and for saving image and setting the view to the image view .

Here is my custom view :

```
public class DrawView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private ArrayList<ColouredPoint> paths ;
    private ColouredPoint mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    boolean erase;
    // Current used colour
    private int mCurrColour;
    public void setErase(boolean era){
        erase=era;
    }
    public void setColor(int colour) {
        mCurrColour = colour;
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // XML constructor
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPath = new ColouredPoint(mCurrColour);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    }
    private float mX, mY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Capture a reference to each touch for drawing
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPath = new ColouredPoint(mCurrColour);
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                paths.add(mPath);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);
        // Draw your custom points here
        if(!erase){

            for (ColouredPoint i:paths) {
                mPaint.setColor(i.colour);
                c.drawPath(i, mPaint);}
            mPaint.setColor(mCurrColour);
            c.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);}
        else if (paths.size()>0){
            paths.remove(paths.size()-1);} }
    /**
     * Class to store the coordinate and the colour of the point.
     */
    private class ColouredPoint extends Path{
        int colour;
        public ColouredPoint(int colour) {this.colour = colour;}}}
```

i call it in main activity :

```
im = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); im.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        DrawView mcustomImagview = (DrawView) v;
        mcustomImagview.invalidate();
        mcustomImagview.setColor(color);
        mcustomImagview.setErase(value);

        if (v.onTouchEvent(event)) {

            // Do something with event.getX(), event.getY()
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

i save the image by this code :

```
Bitmap b2 = ((BitmapDrawable)im.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b2, "title",null);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You paint on canvas no on drawable so try save canvas to drawable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349971/converting-canvas-to-drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following 
to save the image  :

```
im .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            im.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = im.getDrawingCache();
            SaveImage(bm);
```

Save Image to local Storage

```
 private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = 10000;
    randomNumber = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "AppName-" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
    } else {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

and In Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```