# OutOfMemoryException when using large images

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I tried to post an image on Facebook wall from my android application.For this I created a bitmap from layout.Here is my code

```
                    System.gc();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Drawable bgDrawable = newLinearLayout.getBackground();
            if (bgDrawable != null)
                bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
            else
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.draw(canvas);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

            // recreate the new Bitmap
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            //Canvas resizedCanvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
                DataKeeper.getInstance().setBundleToPost(parameters);

            }
            bitmap.recycle();
```

It shows **OutOfMemory exception**.I know that this is due to imagesize exceeds its available size.How can i **resize image without lossing its quality**? I tried to correct this using **BitmapFactory.Options**. But does not work.How can solve this exception?

Regards
  Asha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

for more detail see this link

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

Comment: I want bitmap of my Layout content.In such a situation how can i use  Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @Zaz Gmy is correct,
however I don't think the value of `inSampleSize` should be constant (8) for every image.

This of course will work, but scaling different images with different resolutions on the same scale factor = 8, will cause some of images to have a visible loss of quality.

Instead, the `inSimpleSize` should be generated based on the target `width` and `height` of image.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) provides a good article on how to deal with this issue.

Comment: But this is another question, not specific to this thread. Anyway, take a look over this thread on how to save a Bitmap from your content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/android-canvas-to-jpg

Answer (score 0):

Please check this tutorial and download the sample project.This will solve your problem

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android%E2%84%A2-application/