# Creating a button in java file on android

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm making a game and currently I have this java file

```
    package pap.crowslanding;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Game extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.tester1);

}
```

}

Using my custom layout GameView, I have tried to merge it with my xml file tester1

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cl_bg"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="@string/first_button"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="@string/menu_settings"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_white" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<pap.crowslanding.GameView 
 android:id="@+id/GameView" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></pap.crowslanding.GameView
>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now:

```
setContentView(R.layout.tester1);
```

Will not work for some reason but

```
setContentView(GameView(this));
```

Works, any help please

Sorry if this seems easy, I'm quite new and still getting my head around it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980024/how-to-add-button-into-a-canvas-drawview-android/15980200

Comment: I want to merge my GameView layout with an xml layout or even add a button. I have looked at the question and it does not relate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a layout that contains your GameView and a Button, and use it as your content view.

Create a file main.xml in res/layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Text" />

    <pap.crowslanding.GameView
        android:id="@+id/game_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in `onCreate` in your Activity, tell it to use the layout as the content view. You can then grab a reference to your GameView and the Button, adding click listeners or whatnot.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GameView gameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // respond to clicks
        }
    });
}
```

Edit:
Make sure your GameView class implements all three constructors from its super:

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO
}

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO
}

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, it just crashes and will not display it for me. However, if I do 
      setContentView(new GameView(this));
it seems to work

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Ah, I sent you the logcat, is that ok?

Comment: Ah, you're getting a NoSuchMethodException. Your GameView needs to implement all three of the constructors from its super class, or else the layout inflater can't instantiate it. `public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`, `public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`, and `public GameView(Context context)`

Comment: Ah yes! It works but unfortunately now, the buttons show but I have a blank grey/white screen where the GameView should be

Comment: It might be because you're setting both the height and width of the view to "wrap_content". Try setting them to "match_parent" instead, so that it fills the view. (Also, don't forget to upvote and/or mark your accepted answer!)

Comment: Odd, when I do this, I can see the button and when I remove the button, I cannot see the GameView (or what its functions are meant to do)...I just see a black screen now. Is it possible to send you my app package? I cannot upvote nor chat with such a low rep

Answer (score 0):

You cannot draw a Button yourself. You need to wrap your custom View into an XML layout and add the Button there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260876/custom-view-in-xml-layout) for an example. You can do the same programmatically, if you really want to do it in the code, but you still gonna need to wrap it in a layout.

Comment: As I said, unfortunately I'm not really well versed in android programming just yet. All I wish to do is display a button, any button, when I run my Game.java file. I'm not too sure how I would merge GameView.java with an xml file containing a button