# Saving custom View as image in sd card

Tags: android, file, canvas, view, filestream

I want to save a canvas draw which I created by extending `View` class as image in sd card .In this view I can create any line on Touching screen.

The Custom View class :

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    Path path=new Path();
    Bitmap myBitmap;
public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    myBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap((int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);// bitmap created
    canvas=new Canvas(myBitmap);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float xPos=event.getX();
    float yPos=event.getY();
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
        default:
            return false;

    }
    invalidate();

    return true;


}


}
```

I want to save this as **image in SD card** .

The **main class** is as follows:

```
 public class WriteOnScreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String state;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TouchEventView(this,null));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.write_on_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.savepic) {
            state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                 File folder;
                 folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/utkpictdrawn/");
                 if(!folder.exists()){
                     folder.mkdirs();
                 }


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot Save Image.No SD Card !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In main class I am using **menu** option **save canvas**  .When I click on this the image should be saved in SD card.

I have read many threads related this but all are very complex .

So is there any easy way to save canvas draw as image a**ccording to my code**
in SD Card ?

I am a beginner so please explain your  code answer also

One more thing I want to do all saving stuff from the `onOptionsItemSelected`
from menu from the **main Activity** NOT in the `custom view` class!

Comment: What happens when you run your app?

Comment: It runs fine . I am able to draw line on touching screen and when I click on the  **settings** button `save canvas` option shows .I still have to do coding on that! But I am not able to find out how to !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image on canvas to JPEG file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/image-on-canvas-to-jpeg-file)